# How to join tables and get relative data from another table using nest js + typeorm?

Tags: postgresql, join, nestjs, typeorm, multiple-tables

I have table structure like this :

[image]

Admin can create another admin, and they can create Accounts. So In account table, I have add relationship like this :

```
 @ManytoOne(()=> adminEntity, (Admin)=> admin.id)
 created_by: String
```

Now I want to fetch all the account detail with admin's detail like this :

```
 [{
   name: "account 1",
   created_by: "fa46-f456as-45f6sd-fads"
   owner : <Admin Detail of created_by id above>
  },
  {
   name: "account 2",
   created_by: "f45sd6-4654fd-5f4asd6-f654asd"
   owner : <Admin Detail of created_by id above>
  }
]
```

I have setup only single relationship in my entity : `ManyToOne`. Not setup relationship in admin table (Id) to `OnetoMeny`.

How can I get such a data object using `typeorm querybuilder`. I am using nest js framework for it.

If anyone have some idea how to get data from multiple table. then please help me.

### What I tried :

```
 const query = this.Account.createQueryBuilder('account')
               .leftJoinAndSelect('account.created_by', 'admin')
               .execute()
```

But It is throwing error like this : create_by is ambiguous.

Please help me how can I get this kind of data?